# Why doesn't my ARRIS SURFboard SBG6700-AC have external antennas?

Tags: wireless-router

I thought all AC routers had external antennas. Does this mean it isn't a very good router?

Comment: Short answer: No. Longer answer: It has 2x2 MIMO antenna array on 2.4 GHz and 3x3 MIMO antenna array on 5 GHz spectrum to enhance wireless connectivity.

Answer (score 2):

There's absolutely nothing about 802.11ac that requires external antennas. Vendors can design and build great internal antennas, it just takes more work and may cost more.

Apple's 2013 tower-shaped 802.11ac AirPort Extreme and AirPort Time Capsule didn't have external antennas, but they had great coverage and performance and won awards even years later.

External antennas are generally cheaper and easier to design and build, and they can be made to look macho/aggressive for gamer bros who think that an AP needs to look aggressive in order to provide good "ping".

Comment: LOL Thanks to both. I am reassured..